# How to run the ps command from a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run the ps command from a Jenkins pipeline as seen below:

```
stages {
    stage('Check if auto-scale job is running') {
        steps {
            script{
                sh '''#!/bin/bash
                    set -x
                    
                    while [ $(ps -ef | grep -w autoscale_cluster.sh | wc -l) > 1 ]
                    do
                        echo "waiting for auto-scale job to finish..."
                        sleep 2
                    done
                    
                    echo "resuming..."
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is the output I'm getting:

```
ps: not found
```

Comment: Just ran exactly your code, works fine...

Comment: Are you running in a container? If yes, `ps` might not already be installed there.

Answer (score 1):

Either the `ps` executable is not installed, or (more likely?) this is a problem with the `$PATH` variable. Look at the filesystem which you are running in and identify the full path to the `ps` executable, then use the full path in your script. If you find it to be missing, then install it.